# firefox iframe designmode not working

Tags: javascript, html

i have web application where users can type on iframe(rich-text-editor) when they click a button an iframe will show up. 
html code when user click button for new iframe :
`<input name="add_button" type="button" value="New frame" onClick="javascript:add_new_frame();"/>`

javascript code for creating iframe and designmode

```
 function add_new_frame(){
$("<iframe class=\"a\" id="a" name="a"/>").appendTo(id);
        var editor = document.getElementById ("a");
        editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document; 
        editorDoc1 = document.getElementById ("a").contentDocument;                 
        var editorBody = editorDoc.body;

         if ('spellcheck' in editorBody) {    // Firefox
            editorBody.spellcheck = false;

        }

        if ('contentEditable' in editorBody) {
                // allow contentEditable
            editorBody.contentEditable = true;
             editorDoc1.designMode = "on";    
        }
        else {  
          if ('designMode' in editorDoc1) {

                editorDoc1.designMode = "on";                
            }            

        }   

    }
```

I have tested above on (chrome,opera,safari,IE) and it's working fine. However, it's not working on FF, the iframe is showing up but i cannot edit it (designmode is not working).
is there any solution? 
sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

You missed \ in your iframe element to mask the "

```
function add_new_frame(){
$("<iframe class=\"a\" id=\"a\" name=\"a\"/>").appendTo(id);
        var editor = document.getElementById ("a");
        editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document; 
        editorDoc1 = document.getElementById ("a").contentDocument;                 
        var editorBody = editorDoc.body;

         if ('spellcheck' in editorBody) {    // Firefox
            editorBody.spellcheck = false;

        }

        if ('contentEditable' in editorBody) {
                // allow contentEditable
            editorBody.contentEditable = true;
             editorDoc1.designMode = "on";    
        }
        else {  
          if ('designMode' in editorDoc1) {

                editorDoc1.designMode = "on";                
            }            

        }   

    }
```

Comment: i think my iframe is correct,
could be more specific where i have to put \

Comment: id="a" should be id=\"a\" and name="a" should be name=\"a\" because they are surrounded by an " and then you mask the inside " that the string is not corrupted

Comment: thank you... but still iframe design mode="on" is not working on FF

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>    <head>   <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $ = jQuery;
        function frame() {
            $("<iframe class=\"a\" id=\"a\" name=\"a\"/>").appendTo(id);
            var editor = document.getElementById("a");
            editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document;
            editorDoc1 = document.getElementById("a").contentDocument;
            var editorBody = editorDoc.body;
            if ('spellcheck' in editorBody) {    // Firefox
                editorBody.spellcheck = false;

            }
            if ('contentEditable' in editorBody) {
                // allow contentEditable
                editorBody.contentEditable = true;
                editorDoc1.designMode = "on";
            }
            else {
                if ('designMode' in editorDoc1) {

                    editorDoc1.designMode = "on";
                }

            }
        }     

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="add_button" type="button" value="New frame" onclick="frame()" />
    <p id="id">
        contents</p>
</body>
</html>
```